# Can sites like Reddit see your real IP address when you're behind a proxy?

Tags: networking, security, internet, proxy, administrator

I was trying to create a reddit account but didn't want to use my real IP address for it. So when I was trying to find a working proxy I kept refreshing the site to test each one, then when I found one it told me they have been getting too much requests from my computer and I had to wait like 10 minutes before I could sign up. How did they then know that all the requests were being made by the same PC when I was behind a proxy? I even tested the IP to check that it was different from my real one and it was.

Comment: They were probably using cookies in your browser to identify your session without knowing your actual IP address.

Comment: How do you know it was reacting to _your_ requests, and not to a hundred other people trying to use the same proxy at the exact same time?

Comment: Its called browser fingerprinting. Chrome is soon to stop this nonsense websites use to identify you. They don't know your IP but know its the same Browser because fingerprinting is a unique identifier.>>>>>test yours now>>>>>>https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: I think it's more likely that Reddit just blocked the IP address of the proxy because it is used for creating a lot of accounts recently. After waiting you should be allowed to sign up again. These are just measures to reduce spam.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this can be detected.  The most likely here is a cookie on your browser, which is handed out by the browser regardless of your IP.  That is how many sites "keep you logged in", so its fairly ubiquitous technology.   You can get round this by opening a Private browsing session or using a different browser.

t is also possible that Reddit did not pick up on any of this, and the proxy you tried was abused by someone else.

It is also possible (but unlikely) that the proxy server was adding an X-Forwarded-For header - this is a mechanism whereby a proxy server can communicate the IP address that connected to it - although any proxy server being used for privacy purposes would disable this.   It is further unlikely because you said you tried multiple servers.